# Manipulating reference to elements in an STL container (e.g vector)

Tags: c++

Is it always safe to directly manipulate reference/pointer to an element in an STL container?

For example, suppose we have

```
inline void swap(int &a, int &b){int temp=a;a=b;b=temp;}
```

and

```
vector<int> array;
```

which contains {1,2,3,4,5}

Is it a good practice to use the following call?

```
swap(array[1],array[3]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sequence containers that's fine. Associative containers, on the other hand, have their own notion of where an element with a particular value belongs, so don't mess with the value of their elements.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that would work fine.

It would be even better practice to use `std::swap` rather than your own function.

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't the case for all containers. The OP seems to indicate that his use of `std::vector` specifically is merely an example.

Answer (score 2):

There would be no point in `std::vector::operator[]` returning a reference if you couldn't actually do anything with it. Your code is perfectly fine.